# How to disable form autofill in puppeteer browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, integration-testing, puppeteer, web-testing

I am testing a form. I have a scenario where I want to launch form with its fields empty and check validation on empty fields. For now, on launch of the form, some form fields get filled from browser autofill history. Is there a way to prevent it?

PS: I can hack it by manually clearing fields on launch. But I don't want to do that.

Comment: same problem here. Reproduce procedure here.https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/4427

Answer (score 0):

`AUTOFILL` is enabled by default in lastest Puppeter version?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: How you are trigger it?

Comment: @CAlonsoCOrtega open 2nd tab with same page after already login/filled same form and submitted in the same browser instance